# VB.NET - Declaration Expected Compilation Error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file

I am using the following code in a feable attempt to write out all files in the images directory of the root of my server...  but I am failing miserably on getting this to work for some, god knows why reason.

Here is the code I have thus far...

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<script language="vb" runat="server" explicit="true" strict="true">
Dim position As Integer

Public Sub GetFiles(ByVal path As String)
    If File.Exists(path) Then
        ' This path is a file 
        ProcessFile(path)
    ElseIf Directory.Exists(path) Then
        ' This path is a directory 
        ProcessDirectory(path)
    End If
End Sub

' Process all files in the directory passed in, recurse on any directories 
' that are found, and process the files they contain. 
Public Sub ProcessDirectory(ByVal targetDirectory As String)
    ' Process the list of files found in the directory. 
    Dim fileEntries As String() = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory)
    For Each fileName As String In fileEntries
        ProcessFile(fileName)
    Next

    ' Recurse into subdirectories of this directory. 
    Dim subdirectoryEntries As String() = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory)
    For Each subdirectory As String In subdirectoryEntries
        ProcessDirectory(subdirectory)
    Next
End Sub

' Insert logic for processing found files here. 
Public Sub ProcessFile(ByVal path As String)
    Dim fi As New FileInfo(path)
    Response.Write("File Number " + position.ToString() + ". Path: " + path + " <br />")
    position += 1
End Sub

GetFiles("\images\")

</script>
```

I get a Declaration Expected compilation error on the following line of code:

```
GetFiles("\images\")
```

Is there something i need to declare here?  I'm just ripping out my hair and going bald on this one... arggg!

Comment: I suspect that it doesn't like the extra \'s in your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline script (meaning part of the .aspx markup rather then code behind) can contain only methods, not commands.

While not explicitly mentioned in the documentation, the naming [Code Declaration Blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cy7sxha%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) hints that it's used only to *declare* code. You call that code elsewhere, or in events.

So, you must put all commands you want executed in page events, in your case Page_Load looks most fitting:

```
Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    GetFiles("\images\")
End Sub
```

If you want this to be part of the markup itself then you can use `<% ... %>` notation instead of putting that in `<script>` tags which will fail:

```
<!-- markup here -->
<!-- .... -->
<% GetFiles("\images\") %>
```

Comment: Except, I am wanting to call the GetFiles() function within the .aspx file itself, determined upon an if statement `<% If Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING")= "id=6566" Then %>` and I need this to be inputted into HTML that is already on the page...